# Getting the error when migrating to angular 10 latest version

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9, angular10

I have migrated my angular application to latest angular 10 version.When Running the code I got the errors like:

src/app/app.module.ts:32:5 - error NG6001:  The class 'DashboardComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

```
   src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts:24:14
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'DashboardComponent' is declared here.
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    //routingComponents,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    UserComponent,
    ForgotpasswordComponent
]
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MomentModule
  ],  
providers: [UserService,AuthserviceService,DashboardService,WebsocketService,NotifyService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**The application was worked fine in previous version(angular 8) but when migrating to angular 10 version and while executing it is showing the above error can anyone please help me regarding this.**

Comment: Did you add the `@Component` annotation to your DashBoardComponent?

Comment: Yes,@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})Can you help me regarding this

Comment: Try to compile the app by using `ng build --prod`, probably it will give you a better error message. Are you sure you updated all dependencies? Can you provide us with your `dashboard.component.ts` and `package.json`?

Comment: I have used ng build --prod even though showing same error  error NG6001: The class 'DashboardComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

Comment: Please provide us with the full files, because I can not see any mistake in the given snippets.